# Using mysql to implement SCD2 logic

Tags: dimension, scd2

I need to process a table which has records likes below into SD2 table. This will require reading the value of previous row and decide it its a match and it then process. If there are no changes in the score record is updated else its deleted and hence mark it terminated in SCD2.

NAME    Score           Deletion/Updation TIME 
Hemant   100            2012-08-01 
Hemant   200            2012-08-10
Hemant   100            2012-08-11
Rahul    100             2012-08-01
Rahul    100             2012-08-02
Rahul    200             2012-08-03

Data need to loaded into table like this :

Name    Value      Valid From          Valid TO 
Hemant   100            -               2012-08-01 
Hemant   200       2012-08-01          2012-08-10
Hemant   100       2012-08-10          2012-08-11
Rahul    100          -                 2012-08-02
Rahul    200       2012-08-02        2012-08-03

Cant use the group by function as same key value pair can be repeated on later dates or mutiple dates. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Regards